# Verificar se borda está aplicada

Tags: jquery, css, jalert

Estou fazendo uma verificação em minha página para que o usuário sempre seja obrigado a selecionar uma `cor` e um `tamanho` mas o meu script não está funcionando corretamente, mesmo selecionando a cor e clicar no botão adicionar o `alert` me pede para que a `cor` seja selecionada.

O que tenho é isso, as opções de `cor` e `tamanho`:

```html
<div class="tovar_color_select">
 <p>SELECIONE A COR</p>
 <?php foreach($ResCor as $ProdCor) { ?>
  <a class="divCor" IdCor="<?php echo $ProdCor->IdCor; ?>" style="background-color:<?php echo $ProdCor->Cor ?>;"></a>
 <?php } ?> 
</div>           

<div class="tovar_size_select">         
 <p>SELECIONE O TAMANHO</p>
 <?php foreach($ResTamanho  as $ProdTam) { ?>
  <a class="divTamanho" IdTamanho="<?php echo $ProdTam->IdTamanho; ?>" ><?php echo $ProdTam->Nome; ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Aplicando as bordas nas opções de cor e tamanho:

```
.selBordaCor {
    border: solid 1px #363131 !important;
}

.selBordaTamanho {
    border: solid 1px #363131 !important;
}

    // APLICANDO BORDA PARA COR 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".divCor").on("click", function() {          
          $(".divCor").each(function(){               
            $(this).removeClass("selBordaCor");     
          })
          $(this).addClass("selBordaCor");              
        })      
    })
    // APLICANDO BORDA PARA TAMANHO
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".divTamanho").on("click", function() {          
          $(".divTamanho").each(function(){               
            $(this).removeClass("selBordaTamanho");     
          })
          $(this).addClass("selBordaTamanho");              
        })      
    })
```

Fazendo a verificação e dando o alert:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finalizar').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selBordaCor")) {
            jAlert('COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
            //alert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else if (!$(this).hasClass("selBordaTamanho")) {
            jAlert('TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
                //alert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
                return false;
            } else {
            // SE TUDO DE CERTO
        }
    });
});
```

Estou usando `hasclass` para verificar se as bordas estão sendo aplicadas, mas não deu muito certo.

A página pode ser vista aqui:
[Acessa a página de exemplo](http://www.rendamaislingerie.com.br/detalhes.php?Id=2&Fam=1&Sub=51)

Comment: Isso é um form? Pq não usa radio buttons? assim sua aplicação fica acessivel e semântica, e você não precisa ficar verificando as classes, tem um ex aqui: https://codepen.io/rauldronca/pen/EWLeMz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu código estas verificando se o botão tem a classe "selBordaCor", porém estas adicionando em "divCor". Altere esta parte do código:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finalizar').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selBordaCor")) {
            jAlert('COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
            //alert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else if (!$(this).hasClass("selBordaTamanho")) {
            jAlert('TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
                //alert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
                return false;
            } else {
            // SE TUDO DE CERTO
        }
    });
});`

Para:
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finalizar').click(function () {
        if (!$(".divCor").hasClass("selBordaCor")) {
            jAlert('COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
            //alert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else if (!$(".divCor").hasClass("selBordaTamanho")) {
            jAlert('TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.', 'Atenção');
                //alert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
                return false;
            } else {
            // SE TUDO DE CERTO
        }
    });
});`
Veja se funciona.

Comment: A parte que você viu é apenas o elemento renderizado inicial, ele adiciona mais abaixo a classe exatamente como você postou.

Comment: mas o código que ele verifica está errado por isso sempre vai chamar o alert, não vejo o motivo de negativar?

Comment: Olá @Lucas, como precisa ser essa verificação de forma correta?

Comment: Tem razão, eu havia entendido que estava verificando a classe "divCor"

Comment: coloca $(".divCor").hasClass("selBordaCor") no lugar do $(this).hasClass("selBordaCor")

Comment: Tem como postar uma resposta, assim fica mais fácil de entender e se der certo já aceito a mesma.

Comment: Vou editar aqui

Comment: Não funcionaria apenas com `!$(".divCor").hasClass("selBordaCor")` porque o seletor de classe traz um array de elementos, precisa iterar em cada um, usando o `.each` por exemplo

Comment: acho que não faz mais sentido ficar estendendo aqui. é só comentários e já está longo demais. qualquer coisa manda um pm. No contexto do html dele funcionaria pois ele só tem um elemento com essa classe. caso ele tenha mais concordo que teria de utilizar o each.

Comment: É que ele possui um `forEach`, no link de exemplo cria algumas divCor a mais. Mas se ele marcou como resolvido é porque o guiou até a solução, então tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você está verificando a classe no elemento errado.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finalizar').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selBordaCor")) { // <-- Aqui você está verificando se o botão Finalizar possue a classe selBordaCor
```

O que você deve fazer é verificar se algum filho do elemento que engloba a seleção de cores e de tamanho, possui a classe específica.

Assim:

```
$('#Finalizar').click(function () {
    if ($('.tovar_color_select').find('.selBordaCor').length != 1) {
      alert('Selecione a cor!');
    }

    else if ($('.tovar_size_select').find('.selBordaCor').length != 1) {
      alert('Selecione o tamanho!');
    }
});
```